# Clearing Firebase observations from a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In all iOS classes that use Firebase you will have code like this,

```
private func clearObservations() {

    // your method for clearing observations, probably something like
    blah blah. removeAllObservers()
}
```

In **view controllers**, it's essential that you call this in `viewWillDisappear` (or `viewDidDisappear`)

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    clearObservations()
}
```

That's fine.

***Assume that*** you have created an observation in a UITableViewCell.

What is the best place in a cell to "clear observations" ?

Note that `prepareForReuse` is useless, try it.

The only approach we've found is

```
override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {

    if newSuperview == nil {

        clearObservations()
    }
    super.willMove(toSuperview: newSuperview)
}
```

Seems flakey/bizarre though.

What's the deal on this?

### Update

Note while "XY Answers" are interesting and informative, if anyone knows the answer to the question that would be great also!

Answer (score 2):

### Preface

This was an attempt to answer the question but the question was misunderstood. I'll leave it here as it does have some relevance regarding observers, handles and tableView cell interaction.

---

While you *can* go through those gyrations, it's not really needed in most use cases.

For example, if you add and observer to a node, there wouldn't necessarily be a *someRef?* variable hanging around. So here we are watching the Posts node for new posts

```
let postsRef = self.ref.child("Posts")
postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot) //add the post to the dataSource and reloadTableview/cell
})
```

Here's another example of watching for any posts that are changed by uid_2

```
let postsRef = self.ref.child("Posts")
let queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "poster_id").queryEqual(toValue: "uid_2")
queryRef.observe(.childChanged) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot) //change the post in the dataSource and reloadTableview/cell
}
```

No class vars are needed for this functionality and nothing needs be nil'd. The point here being that you do not have to have class vars to get observing functionality and you do not need to keep a handle for every observer (keep reading)

> In view controllers, it's essential that you call this
>   *(someRef?.removeAllObservers())* in viewWillDisappear (or Did)..
>   will use Firebase in the cells of tables.

To clarify; I wouldn't want to put Firebase observers in the cells of tables. The observers should be in whichever viewController controls the tableView that has cells. Cells should pull data from the dataSource array (which is backed by Firebase)

There are some circumstances where you may want to remove all observers, again no need to have a class var or a need to nil a var.

```
let postsRef = self.ref.child("Posts")
postsRef.removeAllObservers()
```

There are times when a specific observer needs to be removed (in the case where a node has observers on it's child  nodes for example), and in those cases, we store a handle to that observer as say, a class var (keeping them in an array is a tidy way to do it)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var myPostHandle : DatabaseHandle?

   func addObserver() {
      let postsRef = self.ref.child("Posts")
      self.myPostHandle = postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
         print(snapshot)
      })

   func stopObserving() {
      if self.myPostHandle != nil {
         let postsRef = self.ref.child("Posts")
         postsRef.removeObserver(withHandle: self.myPostHandle) //remove only the .childAdded observer
      }
   }
}
```

Again though, once the observer is removed, the handle would go out of scope once the class closes.

Tableviews that contain cells are backed by a dataSource and that dataSource get's it's data from firebase. When something is added, changed or removed from Firebase, your app is notified and the *array* is updated and then the cell refreshed. No need for an observer in the cell itself.

There's no need to add dozens of observers (in the cells) - add one central observer and let it keep the array current. Refresh tableView only when something changes.

**EDIT**

To Address a comment regarding the use of removeAllObservers: code is worth 1000 words:

Create a new Firebase project with two button actions. Here's the code for button0 which adds an observer to a node:

```
func button0() {   
    let testRef = self.ref.child("test_node")
    testRef.observe( .value) { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
    }
}
```

when this button0 is clicked, from there on, any adds, changes, or deletes to the test node will print it's contents to the log.

```
func button1() {   
    let testRef = self.ref.child("test_node")
    testRef.removeAllObservers()
}
```

This will remove all observers for the node specified. Once clicked, no events will print to the console.

Try it!

Comment: @Fattie It's quite possible the answer is unclear, but from the Firebase Documentation "If multiple listeners have been added to a database reference, each listener is called when an event is raised. In order to stop syncing data at that location, you must remove all observers at a location by *calling the removeAllObservers method.*". That was the point of the example code - adding an observer(s) and then removing all observers. If you want to remove specific observers, you keep a reference (handle) to the ones you created - hence the example in my answer.

Comment: @Fattie The statement *Dude I'm pretty sure you misunderstand how removeAllObservors works* may be correct, however, see the edit to my answer for an example project you can try yourself to see how it works.

Comment: @Fattie Totally agree with *>on the one reference<* which is why I pointed that out in my answer! I think my answer *attempts* (lol) to explain why keeping observers in cellViews should be avoided and your actual question was about where to remove observers if they *were* in the cellView. My observation is that if you don't put observers in the cell view in the first place then you wouldn't need to remove them. But yeah - we are two different pages and I didnt really get the question to start with.

Comment: by the way @jay sorry for the delay with the holidays - again, regarding your final code example above, it is ***AMAZING INFORMATION***.  As soon as I get a second, I will investigate this...........it is huge

Answer (score -1):

It is not right to clear observations in cell and therefore there is not a best place to do it in cell, because, firstly, this approach contradicts MVC pattern. Views only responsible for displaying content and they should only contain code that describes how they must be draw. And in the view controller you give the content for showing by views. Usually content has provided by your model. So controller connects views and model. In your case, when you place clearObservations() in cell class, you also have someRef as a class property, so you have a model in your view class and this is incorrect.

Secondly, if you try to clear observations in table cell you definitely make logic of showing some content in table in wrong way. Cell only show data that has to be generated by some object that conforms to UITableViewDataSource protocol and  implements protocol methods. For instance, in cellForRow method you generate cell and setup it with some content from array. This array is generated from model (Firebase service). Your view controller may be this data source object. You have to include array property to controller class and someRef, than you fill array and reload table data. If controller's view disappeared you clear observations, but you do it only inside view controller (in viewWillDisappear()).

Overall, all manipulations with someRef you should do in view controller and therefore "clear observations" also inside controller.

Comment: of course you have a controller (in the MVC sense) for cells.  it's totally normal that the information in cells, will update in realtime when you have an OCC app.

Comment: BTW Note that the MVC pattern applies *fratcally*.  It's commonplace that a cell, screen, container, extremely complex custom control or whatever has it's own MVC model "within" it.  (Moreover, agent-based software is a more suitable, and indeed now common, paradigm.)